# Unintended escaping of double quote in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, git

I am trying to add the following Git alias as a command in Git bash (windows user here).

```
yolo = "!git init && git remote add origin $1 && git pull"
```

None of this seem to be working. The former throws an error and the latter escapes the double quote in `.gitconfig` to `yolo = \"!git init && git remote add origin $1 && git pull\"`

```
$ git config --global alias.yolo "!git init && git remote add origin $1 && git pull"

$ git config --global alias.yolo '"!git init && git remote add origin $1 && git pull"'
```

**Update:** the error displayed by the first command is

```
git config --global alias.yolo "git config --global alias.yolo '"!git init && git remote add origin $1 && git pull"' init && git remote add origin $1 && git pull"
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

-f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
--tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                      or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
-t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
-m, --master <branch>
                      master branch
--mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                      set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Question updated with the error.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your alias trying to do exactly what `git clone` already does?

---

`$1` won't do anything useful here – Git's alias expansion merely appends the user-given parameters at the end of the configured command; it doesn't tell the shell that they should be mapped into $@.

There are two options here:

- Define a function and run it:

  ```
  yolo = "!fred() { git init && git remote add origin \"$1\" && git pull; }; fred"
  ```

  This way $1 will mean the *function's* parameters and work correctly.
- Write a script named `git-yolo`:

  *(doesn't have to be /bin/sh, could be bash or perl or anything)*

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  git init && git remote add origin "$1" && git pull
  ```

  Put the script anywhere in your `$PATH`-configured directories, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/git-yolo`. This will make Git recognize it as a `git yolo` subcommand.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am new to bash scripting.

Problem is, editing .gitconfig and adding `yolo = "!git init && git remote add origin $1 && git pull"` works when `git yolo` command is ran. it works perfectly.

Git clone only works when the directory isn't empty.

All i want is how the alias can be added via `git config --global alias.yolo ...`

I just want the double quote not to be escaped.